# download count in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny

I have set up a shiny app that knitr's markdown PDF's based on selceted data. The generated report needs to have some sort of unique ID to be referenced in meetings.
I understand that I can use the session ID but I need a way to count the downloads per session. 
Is there a way of counting events outside sessions or counting the number of session ID's since first deployment?

Comment: what is "shinyapp.oi?"

Comment: sorry for the spelling I meant [https://www.shinyapps.io/](https://www.shinyapps.io/)

Comment: Oh I didn't realize this was running on that site. That probably has something to do with the double counting.

Comment: All testing was only done locally and with a few changes I want to push this tool up to shinyapp.io over the week. `downloadHandler`triggers once when you hit the button inside the app and a second time when clicking safe. I am thinking that once published to shinyapps.io the second click would not occur based on the instant browser download triggered to the counting should be right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do that once, so I had some code lying around. It basically kept track of everything in a csv that I appended to. Here I built it into a shiny test platform.

- it uses the `session$token` for the id (maybe there is something better)
- it uses `write.table` and `read.table` because they behave better with the `append` option.
- it increments the count by calling out to `writetolog` in the shiny download handler but you can also increment the count manually with an extra button (which is only for test purposes obviously)
- It has two output, one is a summary of the log, the other is a dump of what is in the log. These are for debugging as the `downloadHandler` can be a bit "challenging" at times when interacting with all this reactivity.

Here is that code modified to be an example like about what you need:

```
library(shiny)

logfname <- "log.csv"
writetolog <- function(newcount,newsessionid,operation){
  time <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
  df <- data.frame(time=time,count=newcount,sessionid=newsessionid,operation=operation)
  doappend <- file.exists(logfname)
  if (doappend){
    write.table(df,logfname,append=T,quote=F,col.names=F,sep=",",row.names=F)
  } else {
    write.table(df,logfname,append=F,quote=F,sep=",",row.names=F)
  }
}
getcounts <- function(){
  if (!file.exists(logfname)){
    return(list(count=0,sessioncount=0))
  }
  df <- read.table(logfname,header=T,sep=",")
  nr <- nrow(df)
  rlst <- list(count=sum(df$count),sessioncount=length(unique(df$sessionid)),                                    
                lastop=df$operation[nr],lasttime=df$time[nr])
  return(rlst)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Keep a download log"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("inccount","Increment Count"),
      actionButton("getcount","Refresh Summary"),
      actionButton("showlog","Show Log"),
      downloadButton("dodownload", "Save to .csv")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Summary of Download Log"),
      verbatimTextOutput("showcount"),
      h2("Dump of Download Log"),
      verbatimTextOutput("loglog")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$inccount,{
    print("writetolog")
    writetolog(1,session$token,"inc count")
  })

  output$showcount <- renderPrint({
    input$getcount
    rv <- getcounts()
    time <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
    print(sprintf("%s   -  count:%d sessioncount:%d",time,rv$count,rv$sessioncount))
  })
  output$loglog <- renderPrint({
    input$showlog
    if (!file.exists(logfname)) return(NULL)
    ldf <- read.csv(logfname)
    print(ldf)
  })

  output$dodownload<-downloadHandler(        
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$table_name, '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcars, file)
      writetolog(1,session$token,"save file")
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Storing the session values in csv makes sense and filtering for unique ID`s works perfect for the download counter. I found that `downloadButton`does work w/ the `downloadHandler` but not `actionButton` and the `observeEvent`does not listen to  `downloadButton`or `downloadHandler`. Any idea how to make `observeEvent` listen to `downloadButton`?

Comment: Thanks loads! Works perfect, but it must be triggering `writetolog(1,session$token)`twice. The count goes up once you hit the button and again when clicking save.

Comment: Sure you dont calll it in two places?

Comment: Did you try it with  my code? That only increments once on my machine.

Comment: Just ran your code in a fresh session and it still increments twice when downloading. Increment Count button just once.

Comment: Odd. It doesn't in mine. Let me make a change to make it easier to find.

Comment: Okay, I rewrote some elements of the test platform to make it easier to see what is going on. While this may not fix the problem directly, it ought to make it easier to see the root cause.

Comment: What is the "fulcurm" server?

Comment: Sorry, I mean shinyapps.io server.

Comment: Seems like persistent data storage for the logfile has to be outside the shinyapps.io server – Philipp R 42 mins ago